# Mysql create database failed (kind of)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
CREATE DATABASE 'some database name' ;
```

Works as expecting using mysql's client.

The same query (different database name) from php/mysqli - fails kind of.
It writes to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
But fails to write to the mysql.db table?

This is actually an issue of a larger problem.

What is going on.  Why does my mysqli fail?

code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("p:127.0.0.1", "root", "showtech123", "mysql");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


if(!$mysqli->query( "CREATE DATABASE $database_name;"))
    {echo "DATABASE encountered error:" . $mysqli->error . "<br /";}
```

Errors:

```
db_name: terarydatabase3333, un:teraryuser5999
Warning: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /www/admin.showtechllc.com/public_html/adddb.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in /www/admin.showtechllc.com/public_html/adddb.php on line 21
USER encountered error:MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem independent of PHP? What error do you get?

Comment: No - that is what i mean. My sql runs as expected from the mysql client

Comment: you get a db error from php? or the query "succeeds" in php, but has failed anyways?

Comment: php gives warning - server has gone away

Comment: Try it without the persistent connection, so that it establishes a new one. Also, the semicolon at the end of the query is unnecessary in PHP.

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE 'some database name' ;` should trigger something like `You have an error in your SQL syntax`. The exact syntax does matter because computers don't guess. Can you please edit the question and include the actual code? (You may also want to try removing the statement delimiter `; `.)

Answer (score 0):

the fourth parameter in the constructor is the database you want to use.

you're actually trying to create a new database inside an existing one.

try this :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("p:127.0.0.1", "root", "showtech123");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}else{
    echo "connected";
}

if(!$mysqli->query( "CREATE DATABASE $database_name;")){
   echo "DATABASE encountered error:" . $mysqli->error . "<br /";
}else{
     echo $database_name . "created";
}
```

Comment: Yeah - with or without the database same issues

Comment: share your errors (and warnings) and we shall share our wisdom.

Comment: The database parameter is just an equivalent to `USE databasename`. It will not *create a database into a existing one*.